# Empty default value for select year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I'm working on a form using ruby on rails and I have a select tag to choose a class year

```
=select :student, :class_year, (Time.zone.now.year - 30)..(Time.zone.now.year + 10)
```

This gives me the default value the current year - 30. I tried to add an empty default value but I get errors and I can't figure out how to get it to work. I'm very new to ruby.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you're using a `Range` as the third parameter for the `select` method. As stated in the Rails API documentation, this `choices` parameter needs to be either a flat collection (see `options_for_select`) or a nested collection (see `grouped_options_for_select`).

In your case, rather than `(Time.zone.now.year - 30)..(Time.zone.now.year + 10)`, which results in a `Range`, you could use the following to produce an array of strings:

```
((Time.zone.now.year - 30)..(Time.zone.now.year + 10)).to_a.map(&:to_s)
```

I suggest you take a look at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease for some excellent guidance about how to use the `select` form options helper.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I added `{ include_blank: '' }` at the end and it worked.